# why oracle user defined function shows error in Oracle Sql Developer 4.0.3.16

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion, date-formatting

In Oracle SQL Developer Version 1.5.4, same code doesn't give any error.
I am currently connected to oracle 11g database server.

```
create or replace function getdate
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
v_datevalue date;
begin
v_datevalue := '01-APR-2015';
return (cast(v_datevalue as varchar2));
end;
/
```

[image]

Comment: OK, so what's the error?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error in version `3.2.20.10`. And I don't think it has anything to do with SQL Developer. There is one thing which needs an attention, you are assigning a **string** to the **DATE** data type. Oracle would do an **implicit data type conversion**. `v_datevalue`is declared as `DATE`, and `'01-APR-2015'` is a **string**.

Comment: @vesan Syntex error, expected: varchar

Comment: @Lalit try it on Oracle Sql Developer 4.0.3.16, it compiled but why it mark as an error in worksheet

Comment: If there are differences in two SQL Developer versions, I'd check the date format and `nls_language` preferences. The implicit type conversion from `VARCHAR2` to `DATE` is most likely connected to such a preference. _Best option_, of course, is to use an explicit type conversion, i.e. `v_datevalue := TO_DATE ('01-APR-2015','DD-MON-YYYY');`.

Comment: @Deepak As I already said, the error will be at run time and not compile time. The conversion happens at run time not at compile time. See my answer.

Comment: @Trinimon I checked preferences, both sides are exact same.

Comment: @Deepak Alter the session as I did in my answer, and then try.

Comment: @Deepak: I'm pretty sure that it is somehow connected to some initial parameters being set for the session or editor. There exist `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` (as _Lalit Kumar B_ mentioned too) and `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` as well. See https://community.oracle.com/thread/2145302. All of them have an impact on the actual execution.

Comment: @Trinimon Well, `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` would throw a different error, mostly **not a valid month** or something related. So, I ruled out the language parameter.

Comment: Guys, it's just static syntax analysis error, it is SQL Developer fault, just forget it.

Comment: @Deepak Man, it is just a SQL Developer popup, rather a suggestion and NOT an error. You could turn off the feature. Or else, if it really bothers you, then use `TO_CHAR`. So, you had a problem '`X'`, but you explained about problem `'Y'`.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I already said I compiled and even give output as well but marked as an error in worksheet. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @Deepak, `SQLDeveloper  4.1.0.18` message  https://yadi.sk/i/NxCRiyNtgKgw3

Comment: @Deepak Thanks for adding the screenshot, it was really difficult to understand what you were explaining in plain words.

Comment: @agent5566 I am not understand what and how you trying to explain on that image

Comment: @Deepak i have explained in comment before image. It is just buggy grammar of SQL Developer static syntax analysis. Take it easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> v_datevalue date;
> begin
> v_datevalue := '01-APR-2015';
> ```

This is a bug in your code. Never ever depend on the **implicit data type** conversion. Your issue is not with the tool but the fact that you are assigning a **STRING** to a **DATE** data type.

You might be just lucky to see an implicit conversion without an error, if and only if the **locale-specific NLS_DATE_FORMAT** is exactly same as that you have used in the literal.

> it compiled but why it mark as an error in worksheet

The error will be at **run time** and not at **compile time**. The **data type conversion** happens at run time and not at compile time. So, your function would compile successfully, however, it will error out when you execute it.

**Root cause**

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='MM/DD/YYYY';

Session altered.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2    FUNCTION GETDATE
  3      RETURN VARCHAR2
  4    IS
  5      v_datevalue DATE;
  6    BEGIN
  7      v_datevalue := '01-APR-2015';
  8      RETURN (CAST(v_datevalue AS VARCHAR2));
  9    END;
 10    /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT GETDATE FROM DUAL;
SELECT GETDATE FROM DUAL
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at "LALIT.GETDATE", line 6


SQL>
```

So, what happened? Changing the **NLS_DATE_FORMAT** clearly shows the bug in the code.

**Implicit date conversion**

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY';

Session altered.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT GETDATE FROM DUAL;

GETDATE
-----------------------------------------------------
01-APR-2015

SQL>
```

Now, with the same format as that of the literal, the code managed to give an output because Oracle has successfully done the implicit data type conversion.

**Fix**

Always use **TO_DATE** to **explicitly convert a literal into DATE**. Never depend on the **implicit conversion**. **TO_DATE** at **individual SQL statement level**, will **override the NLS settings of your client tool**.

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='MM/DD/YYYY';

Session altered.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2    FUNCTION GETDATE
  3      RETURN VARCHAR2
  4    IS
  5      v_datevalue DATE;
  6    BEGIN
  7      v_datevalue := TO_DATE('01-APR-2015','DD-MON-YYYY');
  8      RETURN (CAST(v_datevalue AS VARCHAR2));
  9    END;
 10    /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT GETDATE FROM DUAL;

GETDATE
-------------------------------------------------------------
04/01/2015

SQL>
```

Comment: "however, it will error out when you execute it." I executed and it give result as well. But still it marked underline as an error. I just want to know the reason.

Comment: *underline* What underline? Can you show the way I have demonstrated. Please edit your question and paste the output.

Comment: I want to attach screen shot first but I am a new member on this forum, you  know 10 rep. points.

Comment: No need of screenshot, execute as script, and copy paste the output as text.

Comment: check out screen shot

Comment: I see the screenshot, but where does it throws an error. It is message popup on the screen. Your functions has compiled successfully. Just execute the SQL using the function `select getdate from dual;` and see if you get an error or not. Probably, it is very old version of SQL Developer, when the `VARCHAR2` data type was introduced. However, it is just a guess. And you don't have to worry about it. Or else, if you are really concerned about that message, then instead of `CAST`, use `TO_CHAR`, Oracle would convert the date into a string.

Comment: The answer does not correspond to the question

Comment: @agent5566 It is a typical XY problem. But still, the answer brings out a very important problem in the code, implicit date conversion.

Comment: @Deepak, and what about the fix you implemented `TO_DATE` in your code after the suggestions?

Comment: To_date works fine, I already tried it yesterday, I raise the  question for cast function, what's wrong with this.

Comment: There is no problem with CAST or anything in your code. The message which you see is a popup from SQL Developer. If you want you could turn it off.

Comment: @LalitKumarB But this popup doesn't come up with to_char function.

Comment: Because with `to_char` you don't have to explicitly cast as varchar2. So, no varchar2, no message from SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

error has occurred
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYAfw.png)